# Allow JavaScript Ontouch Event in Android Webview

Tags: android

Hi i am trying Jpageflip in android webview. there is no issue when running on firefox & chrome. but in android browse cant able to get pageflip.javascript ontouctevent is not running. how to enable this? for information about jpageflip visit www.jpageflip.de

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable javascript for your WebView.

```
WebView wv = ...;

...

wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: actually thats not issue. javascript ontouch event alone not working.

Comment: Have you tried this:
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true); ?

Comment: ya i have tried. but cant able to get result. actually javascript  is working but particularly ontouch event functionality is not working